# Re-create uri from decoded string

Tags: android

I get an Uri and I do:

```
String s = Uri.decode(uri.toString());
```

But when I encode the string again I haven't got the same result:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(Uri.encode(s));
```

Uri received without decoding (just called toString()):

```
content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3APictures%2FScreenshots%2FScreenshot_20190807-153556.png
```

Uri created via parse/encode method:

```
content%3A%2F%2Fcom.android.externalstorage.documents%2Fdocument%2Fprimary%3APictures%2FScreenshots%2FScreenshot_20190807-153556.png
```

Is there a way to re-parse correctly the Uri?

Comment: can't you just skip encoding/decoding? that string has nothing which would need to be encoded, eg `%20`. for filenames with a space `.replace()` would not encode too much.

Comment: No because I need to show the decoded string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to re-parse correctly the Uri?

No. Hold onto the original `Uri`. This is not significantly different than converting an image to monochrome, then wondering how to get the original color image back. The `decode()` and `encode()` methods are not designed to decode and encode `Uri` values, but rather specific pieces (e.g., query parameter values).

Answer (score 0):

`URLEncoder.encode` and `URLDecoder.decode` did the job for me:

```
    val uri1 = "content://media/external/images/media/1000000076"
    Timber.v("uri1=$uri1")
    val str = URLEncoder.encode(uri1, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString())
    Timber.v("str=$str")
    val uri2 = URLDecoder.decode(str, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString())
    Timber.v("uri2=$uri2")
```

I get following output:

```
uri1=content://media/external/images/media/1000000076
str=content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F1000000076
uri2=content://media/external/images/media/1000000076
```

Also worked for original poster string:

```
uri1=content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3APictures%2FScreenshots%2FScreenshot_20190807-153556.png
str=content%3A%2F%2Fcom.android.externalstorage.documents%2Fdocument%2Fprimary%253APictures%252FScreenshots%252FScreenshot_20190807-153556.png
uri2=content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3APictures%2FScreenshots%2FScreenshot_20190807-153556.png
```